# cucumber can find feature file but not generating helper methods - using groovy and geb

Tags: groovy, cucumber, bdd, geb

I am trying to setup BDD framework where I would like to have:

- my page files (geb pages ) inside src/main/groovy
- the features file inside src/test/resources
- the step definition files inside src/test/groovy

I am using [this gradle-cucumber-plugin](https://github.com/samueltbrown/gradle-cucumber-plugin)

Problem: The cucumber task is able to locate the feature file but is not generating helper methods in groovy. Not sure what I am missing, please help...

[click here to see project-setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho8Xg.png)

```
 plugins { id "com.github.samueltbrown.cucumber" version "0.9" }
 group 'com.orbitz.cucumber'
 version '1.0'
 apply plugin: 'java'
 apply plugin: 'groovy'
 apply plugin: 'idea'
 def gebVersion = "0.9.2"
 def seleniumVersion = '2.46.0'
 def driver = "firefox"
 def cucumberJvmVersion = '1.2.2'
 sourceCompatibility = 1.7
 repositories { mavenCentral()  }
 dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    compile "org.gebish:geb-junit4:$gebVersion"
    compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    testCompile "info.cukes:cucumber-core:$cucumberJvmVersion"
    testCompile "info.cukes:cucumber-groovy:$cucumberJvmVersion"
 }
 cucumber {
    formats = [
            'pretty', 
            'html:build/reports/cucumber', 
            'junit:build/cucumber.xml'
    ]
    featureDirs = ['src/test/resources/orb/wl/pages/']
    glueDirs = ['src/test/groovy/orb/wl/pages/']
    dryRun = false
    monochrome = false
    strict = false
 }
```

---

```
$ ./gradlew cucumber
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:cucumber
@search
Feature: Searching orbitz website

  Given I go to orbitz hotels page
  When I search hotels in "Chicago, IL" from "12/01/2015" to "12/02/2015"
  Then I should see chicago hotels

0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.000s

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
I figured that I forgot to add **Scenario** keyword to above bdd scenario (as you can see from the output). After adding the scenario, everything works fine. It is interesting to note that cucumber does not throw error in the absence of *Scenario* but it treats it like a simple text

```
Feature: Searching orbitz website
 Scenario: orbitz hotels search should work fine
 Given I go to orbitz hotels page
 When I search hotels in "Chicago, IL" from "12/01/2015" to "12/02/2015"
 Then I should see chicago hotels
```

Comment: Note that this is related to Gherkin Syntax. You can find more information on how Cucumber parses the Gherkin Syntax, please check the [docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/)